# Redefinition of'Category' has different symbol error

Tags: ios, iphone

Hi am getting `Redefinition of'Category has different symbol` error in my `Category.h` class. I searched to solve that error.All are telling to add `@compatibility_alias`. But don't know where to add these line of code.
Please help me to understand this concept.

Comment: Are you using core data ?

Comment: yes.Now am integrating my admob sdk to 7.0.While integrating am adding code like @import "GoogleMobileAds"

Comment: So it has nothing to do with objective C category. That's a different concept. Check for solution :http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-avoid-redefinition-of-category-as-different-kind-of-symbol-error-in-xcode/